# *ngIf check if attribute exist

Tags: angular

i'm using angular2 and i want to make a condition to display `something`

For example if `group.permisions=Can Create File` `something` will be displayed.

This is my code

```
<div class="col-md-9" *ngIf="t?.groups[0].id===Can Create File">
     <p class="form-control-static">Can check File</p>
</div>
```

But i got an error `Parser Error: Missing expected )`. I dont understand where is my problem.

Comment: why you removed the answer?

Comment: @Sajeetharan.. no i don't remove any answer...

Comment: I meant u marked my answer and removed it

Comment: @Sajeetharan ouh.. maybe accidentally  removed it.. I'm sorry

Comment: it's ok, i was wondering if something different from the other answer! cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misisng quotes **`''`**,

```
<div class="col-md-9" *ngIf="t?.groups[0].id==='Can Create File'">
```

Answer (score 0):

if your id is a string type then and you want to compare with string:

```
<div class="col-md-9" *ngIf="t?.groups[0]?.id === 'Can Create File'">
     <p class="form-control-static">Can check File</p>
</div>
```